# how to find local webpage host server ip

Tags: networking, ping

There is a webpage where i work and i want to know where is it hosting from. Is there a way to find server name or ip that hosts the webpage? It's a local webpage. Not accessible from outside of company network.

Comment: Can't you just run `ping webadress` in the terminal?

Comment: @WiboKuipers It returns "Ping request could not find host `http://mypage` .Plese check the name and try again" I dont know that should i add some domain name to the end of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include the protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) in a ping request. For example, if you were pinging google:

```
ping google.com
```

Note: Most updated sites will now give you the IPv6 result. Which looks like

```
2a00:1450:4009:822::2003
```

Comment: Actaully webpage was like: `mypage/sub`. directly `mypage` is not aaccessible but when i ping it without http i got a result. I think its dns ip. Now how to find host ip? its ipv4 btw.

Comment: Can you specify the IP you got back? It should not return the DNS IP...